# php xsl extension missing magento readiness check

Tags: php, windows, magento, xslt, mamp

I'm trying to install magento on my Windows 10 system with MAMP PRO, and I have been getting the same error over and over for a while now. The magento installer says that my php xsl extension is missing. To install the extension, [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/xsl.installation.php) says that I have to add the argument `--with-xsl[=DIR]` to my configure line but I have no idea how to do this.

I have added `extension=php_xsl.dll` to my `php.ini` file but it still isn't added. The `php_xsl.dll` is present in my `/ext` folder.

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 13):

Uncomment the following line from php.ini file(remove ';' from the line)..

;extension=php_xsl.dll

Answer (score 7):

in `xamp/php/php.ini` search and modify `php.ini` file, search `;extension=php_xsl.dll` line, remove `;` at the line start and save `php.ini` file. Then open xampp manager, stop Apache services and restart again.

Answer (score 5):

This is because the  `XSL extension` is not enabled. 
To enable the  XSL extension go to the location where the MAMP (or XAMPP) is installed. Then go to `php/php.ini`.
Un-comment the line `extension=php_xsl.dll` and restart the server.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to php.ini file
2. Change ;extension=xsl to extension=xsl
3. Restart your Apache xampp

Answer (score 2):

1. First, stop apache.
2. Edit C:\xampp\php\php.ini
3. Only remove ; at the begiinning of the line `extension=php_xsl.dll`
4. Then start apache again

It will work proper.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this error simply by following these easy steps.

1. Stop the Apache server first
2. Then go to C:\xampp\php
3. Open php.ini file
4. Then uncomment all required extensions (;extension=xsl to extension=xsl)
5. Save it and exit
6. Then start xampp again and try to install

Answer (score 1):

After what seemed like a million frustrating attempts, I finally came across this page and the note above. For some reason, the php.ini file in my MampPro php 7.0.9 was missing the intl and xsl dll (even though I kept uncommenting the ";"

Anyway - I saw the note above and was able to make the amends -- and voila, the issue was resolved.

I wish somehow this info was made available in php documentation and in MampPro site too. Hopefully, this won't be an issue in future patches or updates.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your php root folder,

Copy all icu* * * *.dll files:
from C:\xampp\php

to C:\xampp\apache\bin

Answer (score 0):

Are your other ext you've loaded in php.ini working nomarlly ?.(Try php_info())
And did you think u've download correctly .dll file.

Comment: Yes the other ext i've loaded are working normally, and the file is from a php 5 installation so that may be the issue, but I can't find a php7 php_xsl.dll.

Comment: So i think u should use php 5.6 than u will dont get this problem.Cuz im never tried php7 then i dont know what i need to say. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was installing Magento 2.1 on MAMP PRO WINDOWS (something that is not supported and not done) as a total newbie.

The same problem popped up intl en xsl extensions missing while ; was removed.

After trying everything I just looked at the php.ini location phpinfo()
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Appsolute\MAMPPRO\conf\php7.0.6.ini

Copied the php7.0.6.ini I changed on several locations an many times just into this windows directory and all my troubles were gone.

Answer (score 0):

Magento is often installed on Linux.  The title of this question above doesn't specify the server but the question does so I stumbled on this answer though I was looking for the Linux solution.  So if anyone is looking for how to enable the xsl extension on Ubuntu, the answer is here:  [Enable XSL on Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676127/enable-xsl-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

Search for php.ini in php fold and remove ; from ;extension=php_xsl.dll and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

The most upvoted answers are not telling you where to go to edit these files. 
The correct path is: `C:\MAMPPRO\conf\php(version number here)`
Then you can remove the ; from the line extension=php_xsl.dll and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

In Installer.php line 545 error in magento 2.4.1

uncomment the following in your php.ini file by removing ";" for

```
;extension=intl
;extension=soap
;extension=xsl
;extension=sockets
```